# Stack GUI in java swing

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, stack

I am creating a GUI of stack. Here is my code

```
    private void StackActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                      

    b1=new JButton("Push");
    b2=new JButton("Pop");
    b3=new JButton("Peek");
    b4=new JButton("Clear");
    b1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            pushButtonActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });
    tb.add(b1);
    tb.add(b2);
    tb.add(b3);
    tb.add(b4);
    frame_st.add(tb);
    revalidate();
    repaint();
    frame_st.setSize(1022, 534);
    drawstack();

}                                     
public void drawstack()
{
    m1.setBorder(BorderFactory.createRaisedSoftBevelBorder());
    m1.setBackground(Color.white);
    m1.setLayout(null);
    JLabel l1=new JLabel("STACK");
    l1.setBounds(500, 5, 100, 70);
    m1.add(l1); 
}
```

My code is compiling prefectly drawstack() is drawing the things which is required but as the drawstack() is called my buttons which are present in  StackActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) i.e b1,b2,etc becomes invisible. I don't want this to happen . I want my buttons visible all the time. please help .
m1 is a panel which covers my entire frame.

Comment: Your question is unanswerable as asked. What is m1? How is it related to the other components that you show in the code above?

Comment: m1 is a panel which covers my entire frame

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels i have mentioned what "m1" is

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: 1) Write one in your favorite IDE 2) Come to SO, edit your question and post that code

Comment: Try making m1 non-opaque: `m1.setOpaque(false)` to allow one to see through it. But your design smells a bit funny and I have to wonder if this will fix your problem or all your GUI problems.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you're putting `m1` on top of your buttons (and `frame_st`).  I'd put the buttons on `m1` directly.  Windows like this are Container objects.  They have (sub)containers placed on them, with (sub)(sub)containers placed on them, etc..  You need to keep straight how all the containers at a particular level are laid out on their parent.  If they overlay rather than abut, you have a problem.

I've found [javax.swing.Box](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/Box.html) the most useful, and simplest, class for laying out windows, and I'd recommend it to you.  Put one vertical Box on your whole window.  Then make `frame_st` a horizontal Box, add it to the vertical one, and add your buttons just as you are doing.  Then add `m1`, whatever it is, to the vertical Box also, and you should be good to go.

javax.swing.Box is not the solution to all the world's problems, but it should get you started.  Once your buttons are showing, you can try other stuff.